# VPN-sessions specify the log and how its work on GCP

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-vpn

When searching the log viewer on Google Cloud Platform and selecting Metric type of `logging.googleapis.com/user/vpn sessions`, it is showing:

> 2020-02-17 15:51:28.909 IST Stackdriver Logging API UpdateLogMetric vpn-sessions xyz@gmail.com INVALID_ARGUMENT

Can any one please suggest to me what *INVALID_ARGUMENT* is and how does it relate to this VPN sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps trying to use a [custom metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics)? I do see that you have a metric name (path) type which contains "user". If you are using a custom metric, the syntax you are using “vpn sessions”, contains ‘whitespace’ and is also not currently listed as one of the [built in metrics for VPN](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-vpn). In the log output line you shared, I can see “vpn-sessions” (includes a dash). It is worth pointing out that as per the [Naming Conventions(rules) for metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/metrics-details#label_names), using a “-” (dash) in the metric name is not permitted. Whereas an “_” (underscore) is permitted. This possible name discrepancy could be part of the source for the “INVALID_ARGUMENT” error.

If you are not trying to use custom metrics, would you be able to share where you are seeing the metric for “vpn-sessions” listed? Are you able to see other VPN related metrics in Stackdriver?